# Catching signals other than SIGINT in Python

Tags: python, linux, signals, posix

I'm writing an interactive Python CLI tool. I'd like to have the tool go into a "special text entry mode" when a specific signal is raised. I currently handle SIGINT properly and gracefully exit.

Questions:

1. What signal should I use to enter this mode? (Something that doesn't get in the way of other functionality)
2. What is the best way to catch this signal?
3. How is this signal triggered in POSIX systems? Is it different in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX specifies exactly two *user defined* signals:

```
SIGUSR1 = 30
SIGUSR2 = 31
```

These two signals aren't triggered by any action, meaning you can explicitly define handlers for these and raise these signals for your purpose.

```
import signal

def handler(signum):
   if signum == signal.SIGUSR1:
       print('user defined interrupt!')

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
```

These signals have been provided explicitly for the user's purpose, so it would be a good idea to raise and handle these signals in your application.

---

To explicitly raise this signal with code, you would have to use:

```
import os
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)
```

Where `os.getpid()` returns the process ID of the current process. Replace this with the ID of the process you wish to kill (if it isn't the current one).

Also, I should mention that `SIGUSR1/2` are not supported in Windows. The documentation mentions that besides `SIGABRT`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, `SIGINT`, `SIGSEGV`, or `SIGTERM`, no other signal can be raised. A ValueError will be raised in any other case.

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you! I can't seem to find what CTRL sequences actually triggers these... do you know what they are?

Comment: Oh... sorry. I should have mentioned. You'll have to explicitly raise this with code: `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGUSR1)` (or whatever process you want to interrupt). Besides SIGINT and SIGKILL, none of the other signals (I believe) are keyboard interrupts -- those are the only two.

Comment: @Princey: You'll have to figure out some viable stopping condition upon which you manually raise that signal and interrupt your process. Hmm, this is where you can get inventive :)

Comment: @Princey Should also mention these two signals are not available on Windows. Use with caution!

Comment: Ah! I see. So, is there any way for the user to trigger this from inside the interactive app? :-/

Comment: Maybe a side note: can ESC be used to trigger functionality a-la vim?

Comment: @Princey, I would suggest the user raising a SIGINT that you capture and then from the handler raise a SOGUSR1, but that would defeat the purpose. Honestly I haven't worked with signals enough to answer those questions... I apologise!

Comment: Maybe you could assign Esc to a callback with a plugin? I'm just throwing ideas here!

Comment: All good ideas. Will do some more searching. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `signal` from the standard library. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#example) is an example.
In general, you designate a handler for a specific signal, i.e.:

```
import signal
import time
import sys

def handler(signum, frame):
    print(signum, frame)
    sys.exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

So, when you press C-c, `handler` is run with the signal number and the current stack frame as arguments (if you don't exit there, then the program continues its execution). You can catch other signals in the same way (signal.SIGHUP etc).
For example, to handle a user-reserved signal, you can use `signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)`, and then `kill -USR1 <pid>` from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other way to trigger SIGUSR1 like a CTRL sequence? Or from inside the interactive CLI app?

Comment: You can use `psutil` to get your process as a `Process` object, and then call `send_signal` on it (have a look at the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.send_signal) on how to do it). As for control sequences, I have found [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/sigusr1-from-keyboard-511146/) link that shows a way using traps in a bash script.